# how to set UserName in TiddlyWiki using cookies

Tags: javascript, session-cookies, tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

how to set UserName in TiddlyWiki5 using cookies?
It's annoying to set UserName everytime after a refersh in Chrome. Thank you.

something like

```
$:/status/UserName = document.cookie.split("; UserName=")[1]
```